# problems with search engine on dnn

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9, dnn9

I'm having problems when indexing content on dnn search engine.

I have a provider that use dnn and  I have an admin user. They tell me that they have another customer that use the search engine and works well.

They pre config everything and is not working.

I have tried to find in the documentation, but I could not find anything about this.

I checked for the skin objects, but it looks fine. Then I added vocabulary and check the tags on some pages. I also checked for the crawler API and is not indexing anything.

https://www.colombiantourist.com/DesktopModules/internalservices/API/searchService/preview?keywords=dnn&culture=es-ES

Maybe I am missing something?

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="SEARCH" Src="~/Admin/Skins/Search.ascx" %>

<dnn:SEARCH ID="dnnSearch" runat="server" ShowSite="false" ShowWeb="false" EnableTheming="true" Submit="Search" CssClass="SearchButton" />
```

Comment: What version of DNN are you using?

Comment: this is on the left panel, DNN PLATFORM v. 09.02.00 (366)

Answer (score 0):

Try go to https://www.colombiantourist.com/Search-Results

In Edit mode, open the module Settings

Check if all set correctly
[image]

Comment: i dont have all that options, but i have check all on that screen.

Answer (score 0):

There are many components to the search story on DNN - site config, module config, scheduled indexing, user permissions to name a few. If you are getting search results on the site but they are stale then check the search scheduler to see that it has performed a recent re-index.
[see successfull indexing task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Co60m.png)

If there are no results at all and you have access to the code base then do a clean index by browsing to root / app_data / search and delete all files in that folder then manually start the scheduled task (find scheduler in the admin settings) . If you don't have access to code base you can re-index from the admin menu Site Settings --> search Tab [see search settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/684KU.png)

Note the warnings about when to complete a re-index for large sites. Also note that deleting files manually affects all sites on that DNN instance.

Select a test page and ensure that the page and module settings are set to allow indexing of content.

Re-index content as explained above

Hope this helps

Comment: I dont have acces to the code base, i checked a page configuration and reindex the content but it did not work. I see that i dont have the same options that you have.

Comment: you will need to get superUser (host) access to look at the scheduler to ensure that 1. It is actually running 2. the search crawler task is enabled and performing correctly

Comment: Thanks, the problem was that the provider does not have the scheduler on.

Comment: Fantastic news! Vote up my answer please

Comment: I did it, but I dont have enought reputation.